# How do I copy part of a row of a 2d array into a 1d array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a `double` 2d array that is filled with weather data. Each row is formatted in the same way, the first two numbers are the longitude and latitude of a location and the remaining numbers of the row is the actual weather data of that location. How should I go about finding a specific row and copying only the remaining numbers after index 1 of the row into a 1d array (basically ignoring the first two indexes)?

So far I tried:

```
int x = 0; //index for new 1d array
   for(int i = 0; i <= weather.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < weather[i].length; j++) {

//checks if this row's data is for the correct location
            if(weather[i][j] == longitude && weather[i+1][j+1] == latitude) {

/* if the current element is the latitude, that means all of the values after the ith 
index is the relevant data and can be copied into the new 1d array*/ 
                data[x] = weather[i+1][j+1];
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
```

But this obviously doesn't work. I can't seem to wrap my head around the logic for doing this. I would appreciate any feedback

Answer (score 0):

You access a specific row using the element index:

```
double[] specificRow = weather[index];
```

You copy everything after index 1 using something like [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(double%5B%5D,int,int)):

```
double[] copy = Arrays.copyOfRange(specificRow, 2, specificRow.length);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without importing ```Arrays```?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be several bugs in the implementation:

- `i <= weather.length` - likely to cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
- `(weather[i][j] == longitude && weather[i+1][j+1] == latitude)` - the data from different rows are compared; also comparing doubles should be implemented with a threshold.

If `Arrays.copyOfRange` cannot be used due to some reasons, the copy array should be retrieved this way:

```java
// utility method to compare doubles
static boolean doubleEquals(double d1, double d2) {
    return Math.abs(d1 - d2) < 1e-10d;
}


double[] row = null;

for (int i = 0; i < weather.length; i++) {
    if (doubleEquals(weather[i][0], longitude) 
     && doubleEquals(weather[i][1], latitude )) {
        row = new double[weather[i].length - 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < weather.length; j++) {
            row[j] = weather[i][j + 2];
        }
        // or just row = Arrays.copyOfRange(weather[i], 2, weather[i].length);
        break; // row found
    }
}
```